# ubuntu touch on a nexus 4 with OTG support

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

We would like to use a smart-phone as an interface for our scientific instruments (instruments have their own power source).  We already use the c++ driver library under various Linux distribution and managed to successfully compile them in the Ubuntu phone emulator as well. Now, we would like to connect our instrument to a nexus 4 with Ubuntu touch.

In order to connect our instrument with the nexus we need a USB OTG connection. For android, the OTG was disabled in 4.2.2, but enabled in 4.3. Before we proceed, we have two questions:

1. Does anyone know if OTG works on the nexus 4 with Ubuntu touch/ has anyone tested it?
2. Our driver libraries use the libusb library.. should we expect some problems here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Keyboard and mouse through OTG is working on my Nexus 7 2013, though there's still no mouse cursor shown on the screen making it difficult to use and attaching a keyboard doesn't stop the on-screen keyboard to appear. With this, I assume your instrument might be able to communicate with the device through OTG but not sure about the driver libraries

Answer (score 0):

Just tried Nexus 4 with latest stable Touch and a non-powered OTG cable that works for Nokia N900. Mouse wasn't even powered. Note: Nexus was on the welcome screen, because the touchscreen is broken.